# Reload a div of html file in the success function of ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, image

I want to display the image right after uploading it.For this I want to reload the div with id="imagecontainer" in the success function of ajax.

Please do not tell about using ("$id").load("href") function as it does not work in firefox and is very clunky on chrome.

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: simply just change the src with the src of the new image

Comment: @Mr.coder  In upload.php, newer uploaded image has the same src as the previous one

Comment: @user3452721 you should add that detail to your question for future visitors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to reload the image, but it has the same url? You can force the image to load anew by appending a random url parameter. That way, the browser thinks it is a new resource, but the server will simply ignore the url parameter.

```
var $img = $("#imagecontainer");
$img.attr("src", $img.attr("src")+"?"+(new Date()).getTime());
//  my/path/to/image.jpg  ->  my/path/to/image.jpg?1401742135778
```

Using `(new Date()).getTime()` is better than `Math.random()` because the same time won't ever occur twice. This method is also known as [cache busting](http://www.adopsinsider.com/ad-ops-basics/what-is-a-cache-buster-and-how-does-it-work/)

Answer (score 1):

Reload the src attribute of the image. `$("#imgsrc").attr("src", path);` where path is your image's url path.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the source of the image directly like this

```
$('#imgsrc').attr('src', data.url)
```